# MessageQueue object stop read from queue

Tags: c#, message-queue, msmq

I'm using `MessageQueue` object to read messages from `msmq`.

After a short time or when the queue contains `149786` messages the `MessageQueue` object stops reading from the queue, and I can not continue to write to queue.

When the `MessageQueue` is reconnected to the queue it's work well.

My queue is in `Private Queues` folder, when the sum of messages from all of the queues is `149786` messages, the problem happens.

The Code:

```
MessageQueue.EnableConnectionCache = false;
_MessageQueue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:Direct=OS:mycomputer\private$\testqueue");
_MessageQueue.ReciveCompleted += _MessageQueue_ReciveCompleted;

void _MessageQueue_ReciveCompleted(object sender, ReciveCompletedEbentArgs e)
{
    OnMessageRecived(e);
}

private void OnMessageRecived(ReciveCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var message = args.Message;

    if (message == null) return;

    RaiseMessageRecived(message);

    try
    {
        _MessageQueue.BeginRecive();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

If I get an `exception` in the last function I do reconnect to the queue.

What can be the reason for that problem?

Comment: Never seen that behavior. Do you get any errors? What does your code look like?

Comment: What's the message volume in bytes? The actual number won't be important but the volume could be.

Comment: I was not set the volume, I'm using the default volume.
although when the queue\s is full, I still have a lot of free space in the disk